# Strange output from numpy.matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a dataset which contain 32562 rows and 15 columns, in each row the elements of each column are divided by comma ",". I tried to read it and store all data into a matrix with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

f = open("adult.data",'r')
data = []
for line in f.readlines():
    data.append(line.split(","))

print(data[0])
data = np.matrix(data)
print(data)
```

I think in the end the data should be a numpy matrix with shape (32562,15), however the actual shape is (1, 32562) with lots of list([a line of data]) inside it:

[image]

How could this happened? Do numpy have some problem on changing list with string inside to matrix?

Comment: Can you show exactly what format your data is in - show the first couple of lines?

Comment: If you used `np.array(data)` you'd get a (32562,) shape array - an array of lists.  Using `np.matrix` adds a dimension (1 in this case), since that is always 2d.  Note the dtype is `object`.

Comment: I see a `list([\n])` element.  That would be a blank line.  If you are going to use `readlines`, strip of the newline, and skip blank lines.  And make sure each line has 15 elements (after the split).

Comment: I'd try: `np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', dtype=None, encoding=None)`

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have a different number of columns in any of your rows, as `numpy` is no longer able to interpret the list of lists as a matrix with width 15. That might happen if any of your cells contain commas or if there are missing values in some rows.

```
# Example of irregular row length
mat = np.matrix([[1,2,3], [4,5]])
print(mat)   # matrix([[list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5])]], dtype=object)
print(mat.shape)   # (1L, 2L)

# Example of comma in text cell causing irregular row length
from StringIO import StringIO
f = StringIO('1, 2, "Some text"\n3, 4, "More, text"')
mat = np.matrix([line.split(",") for line in f])
print(mat)  # [[list(['1', ' 2', ' "Some text"\n'])  list(['3', ' 4', ' "More', ' text"'])]]
print(mat.shape)  # (1L, 2L)
```

If it is a problem with commas you could import your data as CSV instead - this will handle correctly formatted CSV which may have commas inside quotation marks.

```
import csv
f = StringIO('1, 2, "Some text"\n3, 4, "More, text"')
mat = np.matrix([row for row in csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)])
```

or use [`genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), [`loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) or [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

But in your case the problem seems to be an extra blank line at the end of the file.

```
f = StringIO('6, 7\n8, 9\n\n')
print(np.matrix([line.split(",") for line in f])) # [[list(['6', ' 7\n']) list(['8', ' 9\n']) list(['\n'])]]
```

You can fix this just by stripping the lines

```
f = StringIO('6, 7\n8, 9\n\n')
data=[]
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        data.append(line.split(","))

mat = np.matrix(data)
```